# LED on delay circuit for MANY LEDs in PARALLEL

Tags: led, delay

I found a very simple circuit that delays the switching on of an LED.

With the given value of capacitance, there is a 0.7 second delay between the first and the second LED.

[image: 12VDC circuit]

The second LED has about a 0.7 second delay between the first one with the given value of capacitance (4.7uF).
However, I want to use many LED's in parallel, instead of just one LED (I'm trying to write my name with LEDs where each letter has a certain delay between the previous letter). It didn't work when I just put more LEDs in parallel in the existing circuit. What are the necessary changes I should make in the circuit for it to allow many LEDs in parallel?
I'm not well versed with electronic components. In fact I just barely understood this circuit. It would be great if I got some help with this! :)

Comment: That circuit will switch on the second one when the power is switched on and then it will fade out. Look up "4107 circuits". The 4017 uses a Johnson counter to run a sequence.

Comment: How did it "not work".  Show a schematic of how you connected the additional LEDs.

Comment: A BC557 is a PNP transistor, not an NPN as you've drawn it. That circuit only works as a delay-on with a PNP.